# How to redirect s3 link from rest controller java

Tags: java, rest, amazon-s3

we have S3 storage ,there are a lot of some files, jpg,mp3 and others
what i need to do?
i need to redirect client to get the file from our s3 without uploading it on our server
and i want that clien get the file on his pc with name and extension

so it looks like clien send us uuid - we find link of this file on s3 and redirect it like this

```
  @GetMapping("/test/{uuid}")
  public ResponseEntity<Void> getFile(@PathVariable UUID uuid) {
    var url = storageServiceS3.getUrl(uuid);
    try {
      var name = storageServiceS3.getName(uuid);
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY)
        .header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, url)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(name))
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + name)
        .build();
    } catch (NoSuchKeyException ex) {
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        .build();
    }
  }
```

everything works good ,the file is downloading but one problem - the file has no name (its name still is key from s3) and no extension.

i think this code not works correctly

```
.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + name)
```

is there any way to do this or i still need upload file to server and then send it to client ?

Comment: If you print `var name` before response... are you sure has a name and not UUID? or try to put name between `\"` like ` "attachment; filename=\"" + name + "\""`...  Beside this I have no ideia about not working, everything likes good

Comment: still not working , the name is "aaa.xlsx" ,but when i download it - its name 23dfd-qe23e23-1ewdq-123123 without any extension - it use key of file from s3 to name file

Comment: What is this controller doing? Only return a URL on Locations or are you build a new Resource stream and return to consumer? It looks like you are return a URL and after downloding from S3 directly.

Comment: it is just redirecting to s3 ,do not download the file on server

Comment: Try check if S3 are overriding headers or some settings for this. I've never tried this before.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found solution- i use S3Presigner ,make presigned url and redirect it with simple Http response

```
  @Bean
  public S3Presigner getS3Presigner() {
    return S3Presigner.builder()
      .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY)))
      .region(Region.of(REGION))
      .endpointOverride(URI.create(END_POINT))
      .build();
  }

  public String getPresignedURL(UUID uuid) {
    var name = getName(uuid);
    var contentDisposition = "attachment;filename=" + name;
    var contentType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(name);

    GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
      .bucket(BUCKET)
      .key(uuid.toString())
      .responseContentDisposition(contentDisposition)
      .responseContentType(contentType)
      .build();

    GetObjectPresignRequest getObjectPresignRequest =
      GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
        .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
        .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
        .build();

    PresignedGetObjectRequest presignedGetObjectRequest =
      s3Presigner.presignGetObject(getObjectPresignRequest);

   return presignedGetObjectRequest.url().toString();
  }

@GetMapping("/redirect/{uuid}")
  public void redirectToS3(@PathVariable UUID uuid, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
      var URI = storageServiceS3.getPresignedURL(uuid);
      response.sendRedirect(URI);
    } catch (NoSuchKeyException | IOException e) {
      response.setStatus(404);
    }
  }
```

It works pretty good ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Алексеев станислав

Some work arround for this is consuming your rest service by javascript and add file's name in a new header response and rename file when download by client.

```
// don't forget to allow X-File-Name header on CORS in spring
headers.add("X-File-Name",  nameToBeDownloaded );
```

Example on ANGULAR but can be parsed to other language

```js
this.http.get(uri_link_spring_redirecting_to_S3, {
    responseType: 'blob',
    observe: 'response'
}).subscribe(
    (response) => {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        var file = new Blob([response.body], {
            type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'
        });
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        link.download = response?.headers?.get('X-File-Name');; 'download.csv';
        link.click();
    },
    error => {
        ...
    }
)
```

Comment: it does not work, i add this header and still get file with uuid name without extension

Comment: and it is redirect i do not need to downloan file to our server